# Design time issues with Composite Control with Devexpress control

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, composite-controls

i am creating a composite control class with several devexpress aspx control within it. However there is a issues in design time that is: whenever i change the child controls properties that i expose, the child control is lost its interface/skin (as the below image)
 [image]
Above image show that, leftlistbox, bottom two button is the aspx control while rightlistbox is the asp control. Whenever i access and make change the child control properties of the composite control, only those devexpress control will loss its interface/skin in design time as shown above. 
Below are my class file for the composite control.

```
   [ParseChildren(true), PersistChildren(false)]
public class CompositeControl_TEST : CompositeControl, INamingContainer 
{
    private ASPxListBox leftListBox;
    private ListBox rightListBox;
    private ASPxButton lefttoright;
    private ASPxButton righttoleft;

    [Bindable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxListBox XF_leftListBox
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            return leftListBox;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public ListBox XF_rightlistBox
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            return rightListBox;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton XF_left2rightButton
    {
        get
        {
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            return lefttoright;
        }
    }

    [Bindable(true), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton XF_right2leftButton
    {
        get
        {

            this.EnsureChildControls();
            return righttoleft;
        }
    }

    protected override void RecreateChildControls()
    {    
        base.EnsureChildControls();
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<div>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<table>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<tr>"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<td>"));
        this.leftListBox = new ASPxListBox();
        this.leftListBox.ID = this.ClientID + "leftListBox";
        this.leftListBox.Items.Add("left from cs");
        this.Controls.Add(leftListBox);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</td>"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<td>"));
        this.rightListBox = new ListBox();
        this.rightListBox.ID = this.ClientID + "rightListBox";
        //this.rightListBox.Items.Add("Right from cs");
        this.Controls.Add(rightListBox);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</tr>"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<tr>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<td>"));
        this.lefttoright = new ASPxButton();
        lefttoright.ID = this.ClientID + "lefttoright";
        lefttoright.Text = "lefttoright";
        this.Controls.Add(lefttoright);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</td>"));

        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"<td>"));
        this.righttoleft = new ASPxButton();
        righttoleft.ID = this.ClientID + "righttoleft";
        righttoleft.Text = "righttoleft";
        this.Controls.Add(righttoleft);
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</td>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</tr>"));
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(@"</div>"));
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
}
```

}

I been search for the similar issues on the web but seems dont found any matched issues.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I thought I will Chime in.
You must override the designer class CompositeControlDesigner as the default calls RecreateChildControls - Since Control properties are not saved in viewState they are recreated during this method call

```
[Bindable(true),   DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), NotifyParentProperty(true)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton XF_right2leftButton
{
    get
    {

        this.EnsureChildControls();
        //this is not in viewsate and it is ill adviced to try and put it there. 
        return righttoleft;
    }
```

}

Try creating designer that derives from CompositeControlDesigner
Then assign to your custom control like this

```
[
Designer("YourDesignerNamespace.YourCompositeControlDesigner, " + YourAssemblyInfo)
] 
[ParseChildren(true), PersistChildren(false)]
public class CompositeControl_TEST : CompositeControl, INamingContainer 
{....

}
```

Override CreateChildControls in the CompositeControlDesigner like this

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {

    }
```

This removes the call to RecreateChildControl via inteface property

Alternatively you could override GetDesignTimeHtml - this is obviously if you are not going to call base.GetDesignTimeHtml (this method calls CreateChildControls). This must handle Html (you can do that simply by calling RenderControl on the ViewControl);

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are not overriding the Designer, which handles the control's Design Time modifications.
Since you are overriding the major functionality, it guarantees the control still operates properly. Maybe, it would be better to organize such a complex layout via the WebUserControl...

Comment: thx for your comments, actually i was used webusercontrol to develop the control and it seem have some limitation...so i try to use composite control..could you explain how actually overriding the designer or send me any article to do it?